# Why does Java regex "matches" vs "find" get a different match when using non-greedy pattern?

Tags: java, regex

So I ran into a bug caused by expecting the matches() method to find exactly the same match as using find(). Normally this is the case, but it appears that if a non-greedy pattern can be stretched to greedily accept the whole string, its allowed. This seems like a bug in Java. Am I wrong? I don't see anything in the docs which indicates this behavior.

```
Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile("'.*?'");
String nonSingleString = "'START'===stageType?'active':''";
Matcher m1 = stringPattern.matcher(nonSingleString);
boolean matchesCompleteString = m1.matches();
System.out.println("Matches complete string? " + matchesCompleteString);
System.out.println("What was the match? " + m1.group()); //group() gets the string that matched

Matcher m2 = stringPattern.matcher(nonSingleString);
boolean foundMatch = m2.find(); //this looks for the next match
System.out.println("Found a match in at least part of the string? " + foundMatch);
System.out.println("What was the match? " + m2.group());
```

Outputs

> Matches complete string? true
>   What was the match? 'START'===stageType?'active':''
>   Found a match in at least part of the string? true
>   What was the match? 'START'

Comment: Since `matches` only succeeds if it matches the entire string, I believe it follows that if you use `m.matches()` and it succeeds, the no-argument `m.group()` _always_ returns the entire input string.

Answer (score 9):

This makes perfect sense.

The `matches(...)` method must attempt to consume the whole string, so it does, even with a non-greedy pattern.

The `find(...)` method may find a substring, so it stops at the point if finds any matching substring.

Comment: +1. Put differently, reluctant quantifiers match as few items as possible, and the fewest items it can match in order to cover the entire string is all of them.

Comment: I understand that they do different things, but I would expect *a match* to match on the same string, not change the behavior of a non-greedy pattern.

Comment: I guess what I would say is that this isn't intuitive to me, so while I can accept its not a bug, it doesn't follow my expectations. My mental model was that matches() is basically like doing a find() and then seeing if it consumed the whole input. Clearly that is not the case.

Answer (score 8):

They are supposed to be different. `Matcher#matches` attempts to match the complete input string using the implicit anchors `^` and `$` around your regex, whereas `Matcher#find` matches whatever your regex can match.

As per [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> `public boolean matches()`
>   Attempts to match the entire region
>   against the pattern. If the match succeeds then more information can
>   be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.

and

> `public boolean find()`
>   Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.