# Extract substring with regular expression, always None of re.match()

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract some information from a string by regex, but the result is always None. The source code is as follows:

```
line = '<meta content=\"Allrecipes\" property=\"og:site_name\"/>'
x = re.match(r'property=".+?"',line)
print(x)
```

I want to extract content and property tuples, how can I fix it?

Comment: [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) matches only at *the beginning* of a string. You probably want to use `re.find`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Comment: If it is an XML why are you going with the regex? Go for something like `lxml` or `beautifulsoup`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Java regex "matches" vs "find" get a different match when using non-greedy pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681553/why-does-java-regex-matches-vs-find-get-a-different-match-when-using-non-gre)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi That's a question about Java not python. In python there is no `find` method.

Comment: @Arne `re.find` does not exist. You probably meant `re.search`.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: I tried to tell not to use `match` which expects the regex to match full string, rather use `search` which finds the regex anywhere in the string and while finding duplicates, even though I tried python version of same but didn't get. Anyway removed that duplicate.

Comment: Try `re.search("content\=\\\"(?P<content>.*)\\\".*property\=\\\"(?P<prop>.*)\\\"\/\>",line)`.

Comment: You should use `search` instead of `match` as `match` will only work if whole string matches your regex. Try this python code, `line = '<meta content=\"Allrecipes\" property=\"og:site_name\"/>'
x = re.search(r'property=".+?"',line)
print(x.group())`

Comment: And use `"[^"]+"` instead of `".+"`

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Right, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @DirtyBit is better than using regex. But, if you still want to use regex, it may helps ([RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/eJXmST/1)):

```
line = '<meta content=\"Allrecipes\" property=\"og:site_name\"/>'
regex = re.search("content=\\\"(?P<content>.*)\\\".*property=\\\"(?P<prop>.*)\\\"\/>",line)
print (regex.groups())
```

Output:

```
('Allrecipes', 'og:site_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something more suitable.

Using [`beautifulsoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

line = '<meta content=\"Allrecipes\" property=\"og:site_name\"/>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'lxml')

print("Content: {}".format(soup.meta["content"]))
print("Property: {}".format(soup.meta["property"]))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Content: Allrecipes
Property: og:site_name
```